# Laravel 4 project only show white screen on apache 2.4

Tags: php, laravel, digital-ocean, apache2.4

I'm having trouble when deploy my laravel 4 app to digital ocean server, with apache 2.4.7. I have follow [this tut](https://serversforhackers.com/configuring-apache-virtual-hosts), but it doesn't work. I tried to `die('foo')` on public/index.php on first line, it's worked. But when i put `die('foo')` on the bottom of public/index.php, nothing appears. Here's my vhost conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>                                              
    ServerName foobar.com                            

    ServerAdmin foo@bar.com                      
    DocumentRoot /var/www/myproject/public                  

    <Directory /var/www/myproject/public/>                  
            Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews    
            AllowOverride All                               
            Require all granted                             
    </Directory>                                            

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/foobar-error.log      

    LogLevel warn                                           

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined         

    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf              
</VirtualHost>
```

I also run `sudo service apache2 reload` and `sudo service apache2 restart` many times. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try to give permissions to app/storage path

```
chmod -R 777 app/storage
```

Comment: thanks for reply. the problem was the .env.php file. it's already solved

Comment: Is there an .env file in L4 ?